# условие в html-странице на Go

Tags: html, golang

Хочу сделать постраничность, передаю структуру в html-страницу, потом хочу сделать условие:

```
{{ if .Count > 25 }}
      html-код
       {{ end }}
```

и тут выдает ошибку:

```
panic: template: pages:49: unexpected ">" in operand
```

Вопрос: как правильно произвести условие в html-форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Сравнение происходит так:

```
{{ if gt .Count  25 }}
      html-код
       {{ end }}
```

Comment: Благодарю) помогло

Comment: Закройте вопрос, галочкой =)